Cropping vector by raster in QGIS
I have a vector shapefile consisting of polygons and I want to crop it in QGIS by a raster layer of a smaller spatial extent, where the polygons do not extend beyond the raster edge. I have tried the following which do not achieve the desired result from the processing toolbox:

Vector overlay -> Clip
Vector overlay -> Extract/clip by extent
GDAL -> Clip vector by extent

I have also tried polygonizing the raster into a vector so that I could then clip the vector by another vector, but the [GDAL -> Raster conversion -> Polgonize (raster to vector)] ends up creating these super large files that take forever to load because I suspect they are vectors of every single pixel and not just the outline of the raster.
The original:

The polygons I want are in green:


Try reclassifying your raster first with something like: raster_layer@1>the-minimum-valid-pixel-value then polygonize the resulting binary raster.

How do I do this, with Raster Analysis -> Reclassify by Layer?

Raster calculator.

Can you post a picture

Did you polygonize the whole raster? At least it would be much faster and yield simpler polygons if you crop the raster by the extent of each polygon before polygonizing.

@user30184 I don't see how cropping the raster by the polygons would yield what I want. In many cases I want to split the polygons in half where part of them extend beyond the boundary of the raster

Maybe I did not understand what you have. Do you have 3 layers in the screen capture: vectors, reddish raster layer, and a background image that is just for decoration and not to be used in your analysis?

Starting with a raster layer and original polygon layer:

First, update the raster Min/Max Value Settings, making sure to set the Accuracy to Actual(slower).

Now inspect the raster information and find the minimum valid pixel value (excluding nodata). Here it is -41.

Note: You can also use the Raster layer statistics algorithm to find the minimum value:

Open the raster calculator and use the expression: "rastername@1">min-pixel-value. E.g. here I used "srtm_63_15@1">-41. This will produce an output raster with all the valid pixels from the input raster set to a constant value of 1.
Use the input raster as the reference layer. Note that the raster calculator UI may look a bit different depending on the version, but the principal is the same.

Now you have a simple binary raster which you can polygonize.

Here is the result of the polygonize operation.

Now clip your original polygon layer with the vectorized raster. Result:


This mostly works but when I zoom into the edges of the polygonized vectors, they are slightly offset. Do I need to reproject the rasters, say, into UTMs?

Also sometimes the tops of the raster layers get chopped off by a few meters in the raster calculator
